# Set auto completion for a new filetype

Tags: vim, autocomplete, programming

I have a file, which contains lines of function name, now I want to use them for code auto completion, and only for file names end with `.XXX`.

How should I do it, is it possible to work with `ctags` or Omni plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *dictionary completion*, i.e.

```
:setlocal dictionary+=/path/to/your/file
```

and then trigger the insert-mode completion with `<C-x><C-k>`; see `:help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-K`.

If you want this only for filetype `xxx`, put the `:setlocal` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/xxx.vim`.

In contrast, *Omni completion* gives you more power, but you have to write the completion function yourself. (You could write a function that reads in your file, but why do all the effort when Vim has this built-in?!)

Comment: That worked after providing an extra `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.idc set ft=idc` line, but I still prefer OnmiFunc